# Partial string matching in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 arrays containing string A and B. I want to find all the strings A matches with B.
Let's say:

```
A = ['Battery mAh', 'Ram', 'Camera', 'Screen', 'Storage(GB)']
B = ['battery', 'ram', 'storage', 'Processor']
```

Output array should be follwoing:

```
output = ['Battery mAh', 'Ram', 'Storage(GB)']
```

Comment: I have tried 'includes' for exact match and 'match' for partial match. I just wanted to come up with faster and shorter solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `filter` `A` and check if it contains any element that `B` contains:

```
A.filter( // get only the elements that matches
     el => B.some( // check if there is any element in B that is contained in the current element of A
            obj => el.toLowerCase().includes(obj.toLowerCase())
     )
)
```

Returns:

```
["Battery mAh", "Ram", "Storage(GB)"]
```

Comment: I'd use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for a boolean output, but that's personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

That's a function doing that:

```
let items=[];

A.forEach(item => {
    for (let i=0; i<B.length; i++) {
        if (item.toLowerCase().includes(B[i]))
            items.push(item);
    }
});

return items;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert array `b` into a regex, then filter array `a` based on whether or not a string matches this regex.

```js
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Escaping
const escapeRegExp = string => string.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');

const a = ['Battery mAh', 'Ram', 'Camera', 'Screen', 'Storage(GB)'];
const b = ['battery', 'ram', 'storage', 'Processor'];

const regex  = new RegExp(b.map(escapeRegExp).join("|"), "i");
const result = a.filter(product => product.match(regex));

console.log(result);
```